# Save string output to a file

Tags: haskell

After performing a string permutation with

```
listofstrings= ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
listsWithNewLines = map (++ ["\n"]) $ permutations listofstrings
mapM_ putStr (concat listsWithNewLines)
```

The output is very fine. 
I would like to save the output to a textfile. 
How could that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be changing your last line to:

```
mapM_ (writeFile "filename") $ concat listsWithNewLines
```

`writeFile` takes a file path and writes to it the string passed as a second argument.

**UPDATE:**

Instead of using `writeFile`, you can use `appendFile` (if not, the file would be overwritten every time a new word is put):

```
let writeAndPrint word = appendFile "filename" word >> putStr word
mapM_ writeAndPrint $ concat listsWithNewLines
```

`>>` is the operator of sequencing monadic computations. As @chi pointed out, you can rewrite this in a Haskell file, let's say, `printAndWrite.hs` as follows:

```
main = do
  let listofstrings= ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
  let listsWithNewLines = map (++ ["\n"]) $ permutations listofstrings
  let writeAndPrint word = do
    appendFile "filename" word
    putStr word
  mapM_ writeAndPrint $ concat listsWithNewLines
```

After this, you can either load it into `GHCi`, or compile the program using `GHC` and executing it on the console. If you load it in `GHCi`, you should use `:load printAndWrite.hs` and then run `main`.

Comment: Thank you that executes. But the file is 0 when i stop the command. 
How can i see the output (verbose) on the cli? Is it combineable with putStr?

Comment: @foxxx Just edited the post with a more complete solution, although I'd recommend you to take a look at a Haskell tutorial to learn the basics.

Comment: Thank you @nicodp and chi. 
That explained a lot. Now i am able to run that. The command "permutations" permuatets the whole array or? or could it also give me string1string2 in a row?

Comment: After 36MB resultfile my system breaks. How can i flush the ram @nicodp ?

Answer (score 4):

To "loop" over a list and perform monadic actions, you can use

```
foo = do
   ...
   let action string = do
          writeFile "filename" string
          putStrLn ("written: " ++ string)
          ...
   mapM_ action $ concat listsWithNewLines
```

or, with `Data.Foldable`, you can follow this idiom:

```
foo = do
   ...
   for_ (concat listsWithNewLines) $ \string -> do
          writeFile "filename" string
          putStrLn ("written: " ++ string)
          ...
```

Comment: Thank you chi. 
Could you please tell me how i can put this complex code in a file? Until now i've putted every line in the ghci bash. One after another. How has the haskell file to be in order to test your code?

Comment: @foxxx Create a text file and give it the `.hs` file extension. Put `module Foo where` at the beginning of the file, then paste whatever definitions you want underneath. You can load it with `ghci filenamehere.hs`